# Efficient storage of large matrix on HDD

Tags: matrix, storage, sparse-matrix, hard-drive, space-efficiency

I have many large 1GB+ matrices of `doubles` (floats), many of them `0.0`, that need to be stored efficiently. I indend on keeping the `double` type since some of the elements do require to be a `double` (but I can consider changing this if it could lead to a significant space saving). A string header is optional. The matrices have no missing elements, NaNs, NAs, nulls, etc: they are all `doubles`.

Some columns will be sparse, others will not be. The proportion of columns that are sparse will vary from file to file.

What is a space efficient alternative to CSV? For my use, I need to parse this matrix quickly into `R`, `python` *and* `Java`, so a file format specific to a single language is not appropriate. Access may need to be by row or column.

I am also not looking for a commercial solution.

My main objective is to save HDD space without blowing out `io` times. RAM usage once imported is not the primary consideration.

Comment: Sound like you need a sparse matrix format.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/storing-a-large-sparse-array-for-r-and-python may be of interest

Comment: Alternatively, you might just zip the file, read it into memory in zipped format, and then unzip in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

The most important question is if you always expand the whole matrix into memory or if you need a random access to the compacted form (and how). Expanding is way simpler, so I'm concentrating on this.

You could use a bitmap stating if a number is present or zero. This costs 1 bit per entry and thus can increase the file size by `1/64` in case of no zeros or shrink it to `1/64` in case of all zeros. If there are runs of zeros, you may store the number of following zeros and the number non-zeros instead, e.g., by packing two 4-bit numbers into one byte.

As the `double` representation is [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), you can use binary representation in both languages. If many of your numbers are actually `int`s, you may consider something like [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409752/compact-format-for-floating-point-numbers).

If consecutive numbers are related, you could consider storing their differences.

> I indend on keeping the double type since some of the elements do require to be a double (but I can consider changing this if it could lead to a significant space saving).

Obviously, switching to `float` would trade half precision for haltf the memory. This is probably too imprecise, so you could instead omit a few bits from the mantisa and get e.g. 6 bytes per entry. Alternatively, you could reduce the exponent to a single byte instead as the range 1e-38 to 3e38 should suffice.